# Sticky footer with variable height in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, sticky

I am trying to get a sticky footer with a custom height on my website and it is proving far more difficult then I had anticipated.

Here is a screen shot of my footer at the moment:

[image]

The footer is covering my contact form because I have explicitly set a height of 419 px.

On a page where the content is shorter then the screen the footer sticks to the bottom fine... but only because I have explicitly set the height.

[image]

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff;
}

body > .container {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

/* footer */
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 419px;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                        <img alt="" src="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a class="" href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="" href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>
                                Courses
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="" href="">
                                <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i>
                                Our Method
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a class="sign-in" href="">
                                Dashboard
                                <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- end navigation -->

        <!-- main content -->
        <main>

        </main>
        <!-- end main content -->

        <!-- footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="container-fluid bg-footer">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- footer menus -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h3>About</h3>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h3>Help</h3>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        Go to a class
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        Find an order
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        Courses
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        Jobs
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        Contact us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="">
                                        About us
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h3>Social</h3>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li>
                                    <h3>
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </h3>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <h3>
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </h3>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <h3>
                                        <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </h3>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-alt btn-block" href="">
                                    Student Login
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-alt btn-block" href="">
                                    Teacher Login
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end footer menus -->

                    <hr>

                    <!-- footer subtext -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <span class="text-muted">
                                High quality English lessons
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a href="">Privacy</a> | <a href="">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end footer subtext -->

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- sub footer -->
            <div class="container-fluid bg-copyright">
                <div class="container">
                    <p class="copyright">
                        &copy; 2016 Toucan-Talk.com ltd
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end sub footer -->

        </footer>
        <!-- end footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

How do I make the footer stick to the bottom of the page a). without it overlapping onto my content and b). without having to explicitly set the height of the footer.

Comment: Just increase `padding-bottom` of `body > .container` to footer height ..

       body > .container {
           padding-bottom: 419px;
        }

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your case I would recommend to use Flexbox. One big advantage of using Flexbox is that you don't need to set a specific height to the footer anymore.

You can simply achieve what you want just by changing your CSS to the following

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Dang, that just works... wow, no fuss, barely any CSS. THIS is the solution, thank you SO MUCH.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst You're welcome, glad could have helped.

Answer (score -3):

If the footer has a fixed height, just edit your CSS to this:

```
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 419px;
}
```

Comment: Trying that now, however that does not change the fact that I will have to edit my CSS if my footer height changes, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You should avoid that much padding. This is not the good answer as using that much padding will create issue with other things.

Comment: If the footer has dynamic content you could add a bit of Javascript to handle the CSS rule
    $('body').css({'padding-bottom':$('footer').height()+'px'});

Comment: @leo what kind of issue can I expect, this is for a production website and I want to make use of best practice solutions, so far Mdks solution works.

Comment: No, its not good practise. Never ever use padding or maring after 100. Only in case where we cant use other things. Better try to play with position and top and bottom instead of this padding solution.

Comment: @leo the answers appeared within seconds of oneanother and are not identical

Comment: Errr, didn't really copy anything, both the comment and my answer were posted at the same time give or take (actually my answer was posted 11 seconds earlier)